# Accessing the namespace Android.Content.Res; in shared form Xamarin Project / accesing AssetManager class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As far as I am aware there is no answer out there for me at least on stack overflow or anywhere else I can find that answers this question for me.

I am trying to access the AssetManager class in the MainForm.xaml.cs of my Xamarin.Forms project.

Is this possible?

I have tried the following using statements:

Android.Content.Res;
Android.OS;

This is because i want to make a copy of an XML file and edit it in a xaml app.

I have tried reinstalling the Android SDK and mobile applications in .Net visual studio extension many times.

My understanding is this is not a class that can be accessed without dependency code in the Mainform.xaml.cs / shared project of a Xamarin.Forms solution/project and can only be accessed in the Android project of a Xamarin.Forms solution/project.

Could you please confirm this for me?

What are some alternative options for me to access copy and edit an XML file in C# Xamarin.Forms on a mobile application emulator project?

Comment: Yes,you need use dependency code in your Mainform.xaml.cs of a Xamarin.Forms project.The [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) class is a service locator that enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code.

Comment: Hmm, is there another way to do this? What are some alternative options for me to access, make a copy and edit an XML file in C# Xamarin.Forms on an Android mobile application emulator project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I managed to fix the issue finally Hooray!

In order to access the AssetManager Class I needed the namespace Android.Content.Res; which requires the Mono.Android or Mono.Android.dll reference.

This should have been automatically available to my knowledge with the installation of Xamarin.Forms but was not.

In order to get the reference I had to right click 'Dependencies' in the 'Solution Explorer' then click 'Add Project Reference' when the window pops up click the 'Browse' button in the bottom right hand corner and navigate to this file location:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0".

The last folder in the location is the Android version number I think It is best to choose the Mono.Android.dll according to the version of your target framework by choosing from the folder in the 'Mono.Android' folder.

Select the 'Mono.Android.dll' file you have chosen click 'OK' and 'OK' on the following window.

You should hopefully now have access to the Android.Content.Res; namespace without the need for [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) class  code.